# Manga in which the main character lived her first life as a noble girl and was then reincarnated as a a commoner

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I believed the female lead was a noble girl. She lived in luxury but was unaware that her family embezzled money for their own comfort. Then there was this one boy who was a servant in that family. The female lead and the servant boy fell in love and had a relationship, without the girl knowing he was actually a spy sent to discover her family's wrongdoing. After being captured, the people killed her family, including her.

After a few years, she was reincarnated as another girl, more specifically a commoner. She then wished to atone for her family's wrongdoing and her unawareness of it, which caused the people to suffer. Then she was recommended to be a maid to a noble household, which belonged to the fake servant boy she knew in her first life.

This was a mostly black and white manga. The female lead had light-colored hair in her first life and darker hair after being reincarnated. The servant boy had black hair and he tied it a little bit, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead and/or the servant boy?

Comment: Since it’s a manga , his colour hair is black. And he tied it a little bit if I’m not mistaken. And the female lead hair is light colour in her first life . But when she’s reincarnated, her hair color become more dark

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Mostly black and white

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[The Wolf Lord's Lady](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/07f9fs6/ookami-ryoushu-no-ojou-sama)***...?

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/ookami-ryoushu-no-ojou-sama):

> The previous lords have committed as many atrocities as possible to fill their bellies. I, the only daughter of that house, had discovered that my servant and lover was a spy. And as the people wanted, my life ended with my execution. However, with the memory of getting beheaded intact, I began a new life. I was planning to shoulder the sins of my past life and become a nun, but by some trick of fate, I came to work as a maid for the current lord. Under my former lover, whose name, age and even hair colour were all lies.

The protagonist was the daughter of a house of feudal lords who exploited the population they ruled over to live a life of luxury. Her family was overthrown and killed during a rebellion, and she was executed by way of a guillotine.

Shortly before her death, she learned that one of the people leading the rebellion was Kaid Falloa, a teenage lord who'd been posing as a servant boy within her family's household, and with whom she'd been romantically involved.

> [image: The Wolf Lord's Lady, chapter 1, page 8.]

After being executed, she was reincarnated as an orphan girl, and was sent to work as a maid for Lord Kaid's household.

> [image: The Wolf Lord's Lady, chapter 2, page 9.]

She had light-coloured hair in her first life and darker hair after being reincarnated. Kaid has black hair, tied in a ponytail, although his hair was dyed a lighter colour while he was posing as a servant boy.

Comment: Omg yes it is. Thank you sm .

Comment: @Riri - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.